# Bootstrap CSS not working (Navbar)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On demo.mobilifytech.com , I'm working to make a website using bootstrap. The navbar code isn't working right for anything. I've copied the code exactly from the bootstrap website and it still doesn't do what it's supposed to.

My problems are :

1. Navbar is automatically collapse no matter the screen size.
2. Background color isn't changing, text color isn't changing. (such as navbar-inverse, bg-inverse)

I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Please check it out live at demo.mobilifytech.com

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is the code I copied from bootstrap, I've tried using the expand class but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Your question will be closed. You are required to post your markup here, not your web site which will change or disappear, helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use `navbar-expand-md` instead of `navbar-toggleable-md` on your `<nav>` element.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which do not supply code or markup on Stack Overflow. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

your code is missing class `navbar-expand-lg` this class `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` classes to change when their content collapses behind a button.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-faded">
```

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which do not supply code or markup on Stack Overflow. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer